# ERROR Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'

Tags: angular, typescript, rest, api

I'm newbie in Angular 8 and I'm trying to implement a service to get the data in `JSON` format loaded into an `API` but I've got the following error on the console

```
Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

I've also been reading similar questions for this error but I'm haven't been able to solve it

Here's my .ts code where I make the service call

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn : 'root'
})
export class CarsService {

  private CarURL = 'https://catalogo-autos.herokuapp.com/api/autos';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

 getCars(): Observable<Car[]>{

   return this.http.get<Car[]>(this.CarURL);

 }
}
```

And here is the service:

```
  ngOnInit() {

    this.getCars();
  }

  getCars(): void {

    this.carService.getCars().subscribe((carsTemp)=>{
      this.cars = carsTemp;
    })
  }
```

Finally heres my `HTML` markup

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let car of cars">
    <div class="cars">
        <div class="fas fa-eye" (click)="onSelect(car,infAuto)"></div>
        <div>{{car.description}} </div>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

I'll appreciate any further help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to access to `data` property of response you get. The object, you are getting isn't array. It is object with some extra data, which one of the field `data` is actually your required property. You have to remember, that after compiling your typescript code, you are getting js and respone is parsed via `JSON.parse` (be aware when some of fields are f.e. type of `Date`)

Answer (score 2):

Loading the API, it looks like the required cars array is actually within `data` property.

[image: API data]

You could map the result to the `data` property before returning the observable to the controller. Try the following

Service

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn : 'root'
})
export class CarsService {
  private CarURL = 'https://catalogo-autos.herokuapp.com/api/autos';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getCars(): Observable<Car[]>{
    return this.http.get<Car[]>(this.CarURL).pipe(map(response => response.data));
  }
}
```